# undefined local variable or method `maindata_form' in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My two models

Maindata.rb

```
has_many :applications, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :applications
```

Application.rb

```
belongs_to :maindata
accepts_nested_attributes_for :maindata
```

And in the form to save maindata I render application partial as well

```
<%= form_for @main_data do |maindata_form| %>
  <% 3.times { @maindata.applications.build } %>  
  <%= maindata_form.fields_for :applications do |builder| %>                   
    <%= render 'application', maindata_form: builder %>    
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and application partial

```
      <div>
        <%= maindata_form.label :uni_id, "University" %> ***
        <%= maindata_form.collection_select :uni_id, @unis, :id, :bezeichnung, {:include_blank => true} %>
      </div>
```

When I load the form I get error at the star marked line as

undefined local variable or method `maindata_form' for #<#:0x8451588>

Is this a syntax error or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you expecting `maindata_form` to be defined somewhere?  Are you defining it in your controller as a local variable?  If so then it won't carry through to the view, use an instance variable instead.

Comment: I have defined @main_data in new action. Also updated my question with little more details in form code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to create a form from the model. In this case you should:

First: Assign the variable in the controller method @main_data = Maindata.new

Second: This variable link it to the form, for example:

```
<%= form_for @main_data do |f| %>
<div>
<%= f.label :uni_id, "University" %> ***
<%= f.collection_select :uni_id, @unis, :id, :bezeichnung, {:include_blank => true} %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Basically I did the same thing, I have updated the form code in the question. Still same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should call render with :render and :locals parameters:

```
<%= render partial: 'application', locals: { maindata_form: builder } %>
```